# Automatic Renewal Subscription works on fresh installs, not on updating Version

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, subscription, auto-renewing

In version 1.0 ,the app content was free. Whereas in version 1.1 , I implemented Automatic renewal Subscription for some content and used [IAPHelper](https://github.com/saturngod/IAPHelper) for implementing InApp purchase. The Subscription is working fine in case of fresh installs whereas the users who updated the version they can access the paid content for free. If any one know ,what could be the reason behind this ,please help me.

this is my code for purchase

```
[[SubIAPHelper sharedInstance] requestProductsWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSArray *products) {
    if (success) {
        inAppproducts=products;
        SKProduct *product =products[0];
        if (![[SubIAPHelper sharedInstance] productPurchased:product.productIdentifier]) {

           /* purchasing UI shown here and after successful purchase content is downloaded */

        }
        else
        {
            /*Content downloaded as previously purchased and rest of the flow*/
        }
    }
 }];
```

Any kind of help will be appreciable.